# Issue with mobx actions bindings and state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have some code that should reload data from an API when initially loading or refreshing the screen.  When I re-implemented using mobx the loading animation stopped clearing.  When I rewrite the code in both methods, things seem to work, but I don't want to duplicate the code like this.  I believe it has something to do with binding.  Here's the code:

```
@observer
export default class Vehicles extends React.Component {
  @observable client
  @observable loaded = false
  @observable refreshing = false

  @action _loadScreen() {
    this.client = global.store.currentUserStore.user
    this.client.fetchVehicles().then(() => {
      this.loaded = true
      this.refreshing = false
    })
  }

  @action _onRefresh = () => {
    this.loaded = false
    this.refreshing = true

    this._loadScreen()
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    this.navigation = navigation

    return (
      <SafeAreaView flex={1}>
        <NavigationEvents
          onDidFocus={() => Segment.screen("ScreenViewed")}
          onWillFocus={() => this._loadScreen()}
        />
        <Block flex>
          <Loader loaded={this.loaded}/>
```

I've tried experimenting with `@action.bound` and `runInAction` to no avail.  I feel like I'm missing something small here.  I'm also fairly new to js (I've only used it for a line or two here and there in my 15 year career), so feel free to educate me on any concepts I'm clearly not getting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is in your `_loadScreen` method.

Even though it is marked as `action`, since you are using a promise (which is asynchronous) the `then` part of the method is run outside of the initial action (`_loadScreen`).

The code that is inside `then` should also run in `action`.

```js
  import {runInAction} from 'mobx'

  @action _loadScreen() {
    this.client = global.store.currentUserStore.user
    this.client.fetchVehicles().then(() => {
      runInAction(()=>{
        this.loaded = true
        this.refreshing = false
      })

    })
  }
```

From the docs: [Writing asynchronous actions](https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html)